# Selenium: Wait and visibilityOf element not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I've got this pretty simple piece of code:

```
Browser.Wait(15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("given_name")))).sendKeys(selectAll + fornavnOgEtternavn.getFornavn());
```

Testing this markup:

```
<<form id="egendefinert" action="...method="post">
<h2>Egendefinert bruker</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="true">
        <div class="inputfelt avansertModus" style="display: none;">
            <div class="label-wrapper">
                <label for="preferred_username">
                    <span>Brukernavn</span>
                    <span class="label-description">(preferred_username)</span>
                </label>
             </div>
             <input name="preferred_username" id="preferred_username">
            </div>
            <div class="inputfelt ">
                <div class="label-wrapper">
                    <label for="given_name">
                        <span>Fornavn</span>
                        <span class="label-description">(given_name)</span>
                     </label>
                 </div>
                 <input name="given_name" id="given_name">
                </div>
...
```

This is supposed to wait for up to 15 seconds for an input field to be visible, and then use sendKeys() on it to enter text.

However, when I run the test, it IMMEDIATELY fails with this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#given_name"}
```

It doesn't wait for even a second - just concludes with the element not existing immediately.

However, if I put break points in the code and step through each line accessing this and following input fields, it works fine.

So, why does Selenium rush ahead and claim that the elements are doesn't exist, instead of wait for the visibility as specified?

Comment: For an `Expected Condition - visibility_of` you are passing an `Element` not a `Locator`. So it has to first find the `Element ` to use it for `visibility_of` condition. Its not waiting 15s for finding that `Element`.

Comment: Hm. So that will only work if we are checking to see if an existing element is visible or not then?

Comment: If you are waiting for that element to appear and send text to it and it is also an `input` field, it should be obviously be clickable. Try using `element_to_be_clickable` instead of `visibility_of`.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is being thrown in `driver.findElement` code , you are  doing `driver.findElement(By.id("given_name")` which will throw exception first and you WebDriver wait is not evaluating at all

```
Browser.Wait(15).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(**driver.findElement(By.id("given_name")**))).sendKeys(selectAll + fornavnOgEtternavn.getFornavn());
```

use below instead where we are passing By locator Object

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("given_name")))
            .sendKeys(selectAll + fornavnOgEtternavn.getFornavn());
```